# event listener: infowindow content loaded

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I have a web app (Rails 4) with a Google map. When I click on the map, a marker and an infowindow is created. Then I render a .html.erb file and set it as the content of the infowindow. I'd like to be notified when HTML content of infowindow is completely rendered. What's the event and listener that I can use?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: what do you mean by "HTML file", the content for an infowindow may either be a string or a DOMNode, nothing else...how do you load the HTML-file(iframe, ajax,...)?

Comment: I mean that I set the content of infowindow to a string which is essentially an HTML code. I do it like this and it works fine: `content: '<%= j render "/users/new" %>'`. `/users/new` is just an HTML file.

Comment: The infowindow basically is a simple HTML-div, there will not fire an event when the content has been rendered. There is a  `domready`-event for an infowindow(when the content has been attached  to the document), but at this time the content hasn't been rendered yet(it fires before the infowindow opens...the content is still hidden at this time).